# DOCX4J: Adding a final row to a table

Tags: java, docx4j

I've helped create and then since modified the following to add line items to a table in a word document with docx4j. I'm now trying to add a final row to the table that I specify and I'm having a heck of a time doing it. I'm trying to avoid scrapping the whole thing and rewriting it, but it's getting close.

I can get it add one line, adding the following inside the second `for` statement where `i` is the index being checked against, however it just copies the entire previous row and any attempts to insert a blank object have lead to failure:

```
lineItemsTables.getContent().add(newTableRow);
```

There are quite a few other locations I've tried placing this to generate an additional, but I feel like I'm missing something basic and having stared at this the past 2 days and tried in futility I'm not seeing it.

Code:

```
public Tbl createLineItemsTable(WordprocessingMLPackage input, Map incomingRequest, String oid) throws JAXBException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException
{
    List<Object> lineItems = getLineItemFromRequest(incomingRequest);
    Tbl lineItemsTables = new Tbl();
    if (lineItems.size() > 0)
    {
        String xpath = "//w:bookmarkStart[@w:name= 'LLINEITEMS']//..//..//..//..";
        List nodes = input.getMainDocumentPart().getJAXBNodesViaXPath(xpath, false);
        Tbl lineTable = (Tbl)XmlUtils.unwrap(nodes.get(0));
        lineItemsTables.setTblGrid(lineTable.getTblGrid());
        lineItemsTables.setTblPr(lineTable.getTblPr());
        Tr tableRows = (Tr)lineTable.getContent().get(1);
        lineItemsTables.getContent().addAll(lineTable.getContent());

        for (int i = 0; i < lineItems.size(); i++)
        {
            Object lineItem = (Object)lineItems.get(i);
            Tr newTableRow = (Tr)XmlUtils.deepCopy(tableRows);
            List tableCells = newTableRow.getContent();
            for (int ix = 0; ix < tableCells.size(); ix++)
            {
                Tc tableCell = (Tc)XmlUtils.unwrap(tableCells.get(ix));
                //Grab first element of these lists.  Table is formatted to only have one item in element list.
                P paragraph = (P)tableCell.getContent().get(0);
                R run = (R)paragraph.getContent().get(0);
                Text text = (Text)XmlUtils.unwrap(run.getContent().get(0));
                text.setValue(findLineItemValue(lineItem,text.getValue(), oid));
            }

            //Replace first row of table, then add all rows after.
            if (i == 0) {
                lineItemsTables.getContent().set(1, newTableRow);
            } else {
                lineItemsTables.getContent().add(newTableRow);
            }
        }
    }

    return lineItemsTables;
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: lineItemsTables.getContent().set(1, newTableRow); is replacing your second row.

Comment: your question could be clearer... what do you mean "lead to failure"?

Comment: a debug aid is to use XmlUtils.marshalToString to convert your objects to XML, so you can see what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks Jason. lineItemsTables.getContent().set(1, newTableRow); is adding rows according to the number of line items passed from the incomingrequest Object.I'm just trying to have everything populate, and at the very end add a custom line that I can insert a set of defined strings into.